# I want to store data from an array and need to store those entity's ids in another array

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, eloquent

!!! Update !!!

***The problem is solved by myself and the updated, working codes are given below***

I am trying to store data from an array like `$locations = "khulna, dhaka"` in Laravel. But location shouldn't be duplicate in locations table. Later I need the ID's of those locations (if they are in the table already or newly inserted) in another array so that I can attach them with a user.

```
public function addUser(Request $request)
    {
        $locations = $request->location;

        // need to store in the table without duplicating
        // Update - Now I am able to store data without duplicating
        foreach($locations = explode(',', $locations) as $location)
        {
            Location::firstOrCreate([
                'name'  => $location,
                'slug'  => Str::slug($location),
            ]);
        }

        // need the IDs of the locations in another array - (Solved) 
        foreach($locations as $location)
        {
            $location = Location::where('slug', Str::slug($location))->first();
            $location_ids[] = $location->id;
        } 

            $user = User::create([
                'name'              => $request->name,
                'email'             => $request->email,
            ]);

            // Because I need to attach those locations with user
            $user->locations()->attach($location_ids);


        return redirect('users');
    }
```

Comment: how do you get these addresses? it's a simple text field or you are using google place api?

Comment: I am getting from simple text field and that's ...
<input type="text" name="location">